# Distributed logging in Apache Airflow

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

We are using [Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer/) (Managed Airflow in GCP) to orchestrate our tasks. We are moving all our logs to [sumo logic](https://www.sumologic.com) (a standard process in our org). Our requirement is to track an entire log of a single execution of a DAG, as of now there seems to be no way to track.

Currently, the first task in DAG will generate a unique ID and pass it to other tasks via [xcom](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#xcoms). The problem here is we were not able to inject the unique ID in [Airflow operators](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#operators) log(like BigQueryOperator).

Is there any other way to inject the custom unique ID in Airflow operators log?

Answer (score 1):

Composer [integrates with stackdriver logging](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/logs#streaming) and you could filter per-DAG logs by "workflow:{your-dag-name}" and "execution-date:{your-dag-run-date}", e.g.,

You could [read log entries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/tools/gcloud-logging#reading_log_entries) with the following filters:

```
resource.type="cloud_composer_environment"
resource.labels.location="your-location"
resource.labels.environment_name="your-environment-name"
logName="projects/cloud-airflow-dev/logs/airflow-worker"
labels."execution-date"="your-dag-run-date"
labels.workflow="your-dag-id"
```